# Can I specify the electron's position in the atom model for the bohr package?

Tags: chemistry, bohr

I am preparing a presentation on Lewis dot structures. The package `bohr` is really good to make diagrams that help in visualizing the ionic and covalent bond.

For the ionic bond I am quite happy with the results... but for the covalent bond, I would like to stress more the fact that electrons are being "shared" between atoms. I think the first image in this wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_bond) is good enough.

This is my code, so far:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{bohr}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Enlace iónico}
  \centering
  Antes...\par
  \bohr{11}{Na} \quad\quad \bohr{17}{Cl}\par
  Después...\par
  \setbohr{atom-style={\footnotesize\sffamily\ch}}
  \bohr{10}{Na+} \bohr{18}{Cl-}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Enlace covalente}
  \centering{}
  Antes...\par
  \bohr{1}{H} \quad\quad \bohr{1}{H}\par
  \vspace{1cm}
  Después...\par
  \bohr{1}{H} \bohr{1}{H}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

The question is... can I change the position (in polar coordinates, from 0 to 180 degrees) of the electron in the second H atom? That way both electrons will be at the center (between both atoms).

Comment: *Welcome on tex.stackexchange.com *  Non answer: Bohr model is very interesting from an an historical point if view, but not very efficient for multi-electron atom, and becomes more or less silly when you go at molecular orbitals.

Comment: If youvreally want to o that, you could take advantage of the symmetry of 'H', and use `\reflectbox`(package loaded with `graphicx`) for the left atom.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jhor. It works with `reflectbox` Nice trick. :)

Comment: The package uses Ti*k*Z to draw the images. So, I would guess that it should be possible to rotate the whole thing (except for the text) if this is what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package is based on Ti*k*Z, and it hence allows you to set whatever `tikz` options you want to the relevant parts of the diagram. The package offers the `\setbohr` command to set options for all following `\bohr` diagrams. If you only want to affect the next one, you need to make sure that the `\setbohr` command and the relevant `\bohr` command are scoped properly (I used `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` in this example, but maybe you don't need this, because the relevant diagram is already inside a scope).

To add options to the electrons and this way affect their shape or position, you can use `\setbohr{electron-options-add={...}}` and then use `rotate=180` for a rotation by 180 degrees or `xscale=-1` to flip the electrons from left to right:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{bohr}

\begin{document}
    \bohr{1}{H}

    \begingroup
        \setbohr{electron-options-add={rotate=180}}    
        \bohr{1}{H}
    \endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{bohr}

\begin{document}
    \bohr{5}{B}

    \begingroup
        \setbohr{electron-options-add={rotate=180}}    
        \bohr{5}{B}
    \endgroup

    \begingroup
        \setbohr{electron-options-add={xscale=-1}}    
        \bohr{5}{B}
    \endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jhor for suggesting the `reflectbox` command from the `graphicx` package in the comments!
The code is (only for the second frame):

```
\begin{frame}{Enlace covalente}
  \centering{}
  Antes...\par
  \bohr{1}{H} \quad\quad \bohr{1}{H}\par
  \vspace{1cm}
  Después...\par
  \bohr{1}{H} \reflectbox{\bohr{1}{H}}
\end{frame}
```

Plus... you have to load the `graphicx` package in the preamble of the document.

The result..
[image]

Still... it would be better to know if it is possible to change the electron manually (with the `bohr` package). So, this works, but as pointed out by @Jhor, it is due to symmetry.